# Speed of iterating through DrawingCollection versus using Contains()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, optimization

I've got a WPF component showing a collection of `Equipments`. Each of these `Equipments` contains one or more `Coordinate`. On `MouseMove` over my component a function is called checking if the mouse currently hovers within the bounds of any `Coordinate` of any `Equipment`. If so the `Equipment` in question is returned indication that a pop-up window with text information about the `Equipment` should be shown.

Aside from this, all `Coordinates` contain an `ImageDrawing` that shows a symbol for each `Equipment` (the symbol the user hovers the mouse over to see the text pop-up). These are put in a separate `DrawingGroup` to speed up rendering. Another benefit of this is that if some `Equipments` are to be hidden, we can just remove their `Coordinates' ImageDrawing` from the `DrawingGroup`, and they will still be left in the list of `Equipments` (as they should).

However, this does not hinder the pop-up from showing when the mouse hovers over the `Coordinate`, as this is separate from the `DrawingGroup`. So, to check if a text pop-up is to be shown, I have to check both if the mouse is within the bounds of any `Coordinate`, and also check if the `ImageDrawing` for that `Coordinate` is in the `DrawingGroup`.

On to my question (tl;dr): which way to iterate through all these items would be fastest? I've got :

```
List<Equipment> equipments;
```

And for each of these (this list 9 times out of 10 holds one item, and never more than five)

```
List<Coordinate> coordinates;
```

For each of these `Coordinates` I've got to check if their `ImageDrawing` is in the `DrawingCollection` (which in this case is `DrawingGroup.Children`) which, according to msdn, is an `ordered collection of Drawing objects.`

To do this, I started out with this:

```
foreach (Equipment equipment in equipments)
{
    foreach (Coordinate coordinate in equipment.Coordinates)
    {
        ImageDrawing image = coordinate.ImageDrawing;
        if (image != null)
        {
            if (currentDrawingGroup.Children.Contains(image))
            {
                if (image.Rect.Bottom > y && 
                    image.Rect.Top < y && 
                    image.Rect.Left < x && 
                    image.Rect.Right > x)
                {
                    return equipment;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But thought that this becomes to many iterations in the cases where a lot of equipments are hidden, and that I could change it to this (since `Children.Contains(image)` brobably iterates behind the scenes anyway):

```
foreach (var child in currentDrawingGroup.Children)
{
    foreach (Equipment equipment in equipments)
    {
        foreach (Coordinate coordinate in equipment.Coordinates)
        { 
            ImageDrawing image = coordinate.ImageDrawing;
            if (image != null)
            {
                if (image == child)
                {
                    if (image.Rect.Bottom > y && 
                        image.Rect.Top < y && 
                        image.Rect.Left < x && 
                        image.Rect.Right > x)
                    {
                        return equipment;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this question is way too long and the optimizations I'm looking at here probably don't matter much in the long run. But is there a way this could be done without so many loops in loops? I feel like there should be a LINQ-expression helping me somewhere, though I don't know whether any of those are faster than a foreach loop. The way things are sorted (`Equipments` being hid by removing them from the `DrawingGroup` and such) is beyond my control and hard to change. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you evaluate your approches with `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`? With that you can find out, which approach is the fastest.

Comment: So what do you want exactly? Less code or faster running time?

Comment: I guess my question is two-fold: my main concern is as always readability but I don't want it to be at too big of a performance cost. I probably had hopes there would be a more readable solution than any I could come up with anyway. I'll check with the stopwatch to see if there's much of a difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if some equipments are to be hidden, wouldn't it be cleaner to let the equipment himself manage its visibility? This way you just ask the equipment if it is visible in the first place and skip it if not?

Thus your equipments are also always present, but visible or not and when you mouseover it you won't have to check if the coordinates are in the DrawingGroup or not... it's already handled for you.

Regarding iterating vs `Contains()`, the contains function is a linear search so it will be the same as iterating through the list.

Comment: That's a good solution but unfortunately does not apply in this case. As it works now, these equipments can be displayed in several different places (let's call them maps) at once, and setting an equipment as hidden in one map would hide it in all others. The solution with the DrawingGroups was made, as each map has its own DrawingGroup. Icky, I know, but hard to change (it's a big project and this is just a tiny part of it).

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it answers my original question; any difference between Contains() and iteration. Anything but that is readability.